# Forms example or plugins for mobile web development

Tags: html, jqtouch

I am looking for a good jQuery plugin for form Web development for mobile websites like iPhone, Android, etc. I checked jQTouch, and it seems buggy when it comes to forms for mobile web apps. Any suggestions?

I am trying to display results based on user input from Google, Twitter, or Flickr. Any examples/demos would be much appreciated.

I need some plugins or examples for mobile forms that are not buggy like jQTouch is.

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what you are trying to do, what environment you are using, or what kind of field data you are collecting. Where does jQuery come in?

Comment: Question does not make any sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can look here:
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills
Look under "Web Forms" and it has a number of JQuery Forms libs.